# Access and add fields with a button in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

This seems like it should be simple but I can't get it to work.  The environment I am working in requires that I use NAME instead of ID, so I am making certain that all of my names are unique.  I simply want to get two numbers from input fields, add them together and put the answer into a read only field.

```
<input type="number" name="first_num"></input>
<input type="number" name="second_num"></input>
<input type="number" name="sum_of_num" readonly></input>
<button name="perform_sum" onclick="document.getelementsbyname("sum_of_num")[0].value=(document.getelementsbyname("first_num")[0].value+document.getelementsbyname("second_num")[0].value)">Sum</button>
```

Comment: First of all modify getelementsbyname to proper casing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<input type="number" name="first_num"></input>
<input type="number" name="second_num"></input>
<input type="number" name="sum_of_num" readonly></input>
<button name="perform_sum" onclick="document.getElementsByName('sum_of_num')[0].value = (parseInt(document.getElementsByName('first_num')[0].value) + parseInt(document.getElementsByName('second_num')[0].value))">Sum</button>
```

- getelementsbyname -> getElementsByName (javascript is case sensitive)
- " -> ' (if you use double apex in html you have to slash your double apex in javascript or have to use single apex in javascript, or reverse)
- .value is string, you need to convert it in int

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use single quotes, otherwise it thinks the attribute is closed. Also the functions are case-sensitive so it should be `getElementsByName`

from

```
<button name="perform_sum" onclick="document.getelementsbyname("sum_of_num")[0].value=(document.getelementsbyname("first_num")[0].value+document.getelementsbyname("second_num")[0].value)">Sum</button>
```

to

```
<button name="perform_sum" onclick="document.getElementsByName('sum_of_num')[0].value=(document.getElementsByName('first_num')[0].value+document.getElementsByName('second_num')[0].value)">Sum</button>
```

Comment: I believe you also need to use the proper casing for `getElementsByName`.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery answer because it's the easiest (even though you didn't tag jQuery):

```
$("button").click(function () {
    var first_num  = Number($("input[name='first_num']").val());
    var second_num = Number($("input[name='second_num']").val());
    $("input[name='sum_of_num']").val(first_num + second_num);
});
```

jQuery makes it super simple to select by attributes such as name.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use parseInt function else it will just concat two box values.